# kubectl not picking up the correct kubeconfig

Tags: kubectl, amazon-eks, kubeconfig

Please find below the sequence of operations I am performing to authorize and authenticate against kubectl to be able to perform deployments on EKS CLuster

1. SAML Login
2. Downloading correct kubeconfig from Artifactory
3. Using the downloaded kubeconfig # Issue occurs at this stage!

The Jenkins execution log is as below:

```
Logged in as: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/dev-role/testusername

Your new access key pair has been stored in the AWS configuration
Note that it will expire at 2021-02-08 15:18:59 +0000 UTC
To use this credential, call the AWS CLI with the --profile option (e.g. aws --profile saml ec2 describe-instances).
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Compose Source Structure)
[Pipeline] sh
+ set -x
+ cat
+ kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters: []
contexts: []
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
+ rm -vf config
+ wget -nv --no-check-certificate https://testcompanyname.com.au/testrepo/jenkins/eks-nonprod-black-config
2021-02-08 14:19:35 URL:https://testcompanyname.com.au/testrepo/jenkins/eks-nonprod-black-config [2383/2383] -> "eks-nonprod-black-config" [1]
+ mv eks-nonprod-black-config config
+ pwd
/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/k8s-sync-from-cluster
+ ls -lrt
total 11640
-rwxrwxr-x    1 jenkins  jenkins   11801948 Feb 28  2017 saml2aws
-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins  jenkins       2383 Jan 22 03:03 config
drwxr-xr-x    2 jenkins  jenkins       4096 Feb  8 14:19 vars
drwxr-xr-x    3 jenkins  jenkins       4096 Feb  8 14:19 test
drwxr-xr-x    3 jenkins  jenkins       4096 Feb  8 14:19 src
-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins  jenkins        153 Feb  8 14:19 settings.gradle
drwxr-xr-x    9 jenkins  jenkins       4096 Feb  8 14:19 resources
drwxr-xr-x    5 jenkins  jenkins       4096 Feb  8 14:19 pipelines
-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins  jenkins       2841 Feb  8 14:19 gradlew.bat
-rwxr-xr-x    1 jenkins  jenkins       5916 Feb  8 14:19 gradlew
drwxr-xr-x    3 jenkins  jenkins       4096 Feb  8 14:19 gradle
drwxr-xr-x    3 jenkins  jenkins       4096 Feb  8 14:19 csa-kubernetes-env
-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins  jenkins       1532 Feb  8 14:19 build.gradle
-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins  jenkins        208 Feb  8 14:19 README.md
+ cat config
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    server: https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.gr7.ap-southeast-2.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:cluster/test-eks
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:cluster/test-eks
    user: arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:cluster/test-eks
  name: arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:cluster/test-eks
current-context: arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:cluster/test-eks
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:cluster/test-eks
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - --region
      - ap-southeast-2
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - test-eks
      command: aws
      env:
      - name: AWS_PROFILE
        value: saml
+ kubectl config view --kubeconfig ./config
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://7FE00E432DC6BEB1EB17DEF18DB1B926.gr7.ap-southeast-2.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:cluster/test-eks
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:cluster/test-eks
    user: arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:cluster/test-eks
  name: arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:cluster/test-eks
current-context: arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:cluster/test-eks
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:cluster/test-eks
  user: {}
+ kubectl get namespaces --kubeconfig ./config
Please enter Username: Please enter Username: Please enter Username: error: EOF
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

So, as you see the issue is when I cat the file there is user information, however when I run kubectl it challeneges for credentials when it should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@learner I know you've solved your problem by upgrading `kubectl` to a newer version.
Additionally I would like to provide more information about versions of Kubernetes components and relations between them.

---

Kubernetes `version skew support policy` describes the maximum version skew supported between various Kubernetes components. You can find more information in the [version-skew-policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/version-skew-policy/) documentation.

I'll describe general rule to illustrate you how it works.

Let's assume that the `kube-apiserver` is at version **1.n**. In this case:

- `kubelet` and `kube-proxy` are supported at **1.n**, **1.(n-1)**, and
  **1.(n-2)**.
- `kube-controller-manager`, `kube-scheduler`, and
  `cloud-controller-manager` are supported at **1.n** and **1.(n-1)**.
- `kubectl` is supported at **1.(n+1)**, **1.n**, and **1.(n-1)**.

NOTE: `CoreDNS` and `etcd` are separate projects and have their own versions.

Comment: Yes Sir I know N to N-2 support, learnt from Mumshad course. I appreciate your post.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound as silly as it can, but the issue was with kubectl client version.

The issue faced because I was using kubectl 1.9, upgrading to the latest solved the issue.

Comment: What version of `Amazon EKS` Kubernetes do you have ?
Are you using `kubectl` in version `v1.20` now ?

Comment: We using EKS version 1.16. kubectl we were using 1.9 on Old Jenkins instance. I had the same issue with Ansible on Microsoft hosted Agent for Azure DevOps.